# Linear Algebra : Jordan Canonical form (Jordan blocks and the Super-Diagonal)

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

In terms of Jordan Canonical Form, and more specifically 
about Jordan Blocks.
When there is a definition about Jordan Blocks they say the eigenvalues go on the principle diagonal and the diagonal above it(usually called the super-diagonal) contains the number 1!

I want to understand why there are 1's in the superdiagonal.
I have looked all over and no body tries to explain why there is this mysterious 1's in the super-diagonal.

I hope that someone here on this forum can explain this.

Here is a link to PDF:
http://ckottke.ncf.edu/docs/jordan.pdf

Comment: "I have looked all over": Have you looked at a _proof_ that every (complex) matrix has a Jordan form?

Comment: Hi David, i have seen things about complex matrix has Jordan form, but when they discuss it they assume the Ones on the Super Diagonal as though this is a fundamental axiom without need of explanation.

Comment: I just added a link to a pdf article I want to illustrate, how they explain things, where they just assume it to be a fact. See above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a non-zero vector $x$ such that $(A-\lambda I)^{n-1}x \ne 0$ and $(A-\lambda I)^{n}x=0$, then
$$
        \{x,(A-\lambda I)x,\cdots,(A-\lambda I)^{n-1}x\}
$$
is a linearly independent set of vectors. Let
\begin{align}
     v_1 & = (A-\lambda I)^{n-1}x,\\v_2 & =(A-\lambda I)^{n-2}x,\\&\cdots\\v_{n-1} & =(A-\lambda I)^{1}x\end{align}

Then $A-\lambda I$ has the following matrix representation with respect to this basis:
$$
     \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
    \end{array}\right]
$$
And $A-\lambda I$ has the representation $\lambda I$ plus the above, which is a Jordan block.
$$
     \left[\begin{array}{cccc}\lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & \lambda & \cdots & 1 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda
    \end{array}\right]
$$
So the answer to your question is that you can always choose the basis so that you get $1$'s on the diagonal above the main diagonal for a Jordan block.

Comment: Hi DisintegratingByParts, i like what you have done here. When you talk about "Then A−λI has the following matrix representation with respect to this basis: " and you get that matrix that has the ones in the SuperDiagonal, i need to try to look at this more carefully, it does not jump out immediately to me. I will try to  look at this carefully. Thanks for what you have provided, it looks really interesting.

Comment: Hi DisintegratingByParts, I am having difficulty with the algebra manipulation of the e basis vectors. Is e1, e2, e3 etc going to be the column vectors of the Matrix, then would i factor out the  A−λI with power out. Hope you can help with this.

Comment: By a change of basis, the k-th basis element becomes $e_k$. Jordan form is achieved by a change of basis

Comment: So when you use $e_k$ i guess you mean they are the standard basis of $R^n$. For example (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) for $R^3$.